# delphi encrypt convert Java Code

Tags: java, delphi, encryption

How can I convert the specific code written in Delphi to JAVA?

Delphi code is encrypt code.

```
function Encrypt(const S: String; Key1, Key2, Key3: WORD): String;
var
  i: Byte;
  FirstResult: String;
begin
  SetLength(FirstResult, Length(S));
  for i:=1 to Length(S) do begin
    FirstResult[i]:=Char(Byte(S[i]) xor (Key1 shr 8));
    Key1          :=(Byte(FirstResult[i])+Key1)*Key2+Key3;
  end;
  Result:=ValueToHex(FirstResult);
end;

function ValueToHex(const S: String): String;
var i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(S)*2); 
  for i:=0 to Length(S)-1 do begin
    Result[(i*2)+1]:=HexaChar[Integer(S[i+1]) shr 4];
    Result[(i*2)+2]:=HexaChar[Integer(S[i+1]) and $0f];
  end;
end;
```

so I was try to make source code. it's here

```
int key1=11;        int key2=22;        int key3=33;

String value = "ABCDE";
for(int i=0; i< value.length(); i++){
    byte[] bValue = value.substring(i).getBytes();
    int[] rValue = {0};
    rValue[0] = bValue[0]^(key1>>8);
    key1 = (bValue[0]+key1)*key2+key3;
    System.out.print(ValueToHex(rValue));
}
```

But different results.

key1 = 11, key2 = 22, key3 = 33;

```
value : "ABCDE"
delphi encrypt : 4144DB69BF
java encrypt   : 4144DB0901
```

Does not match

but

```
value : "ABC"
delphi encrypt : 4144DB
java encrypt   : 4144DB
```

Is consistent

Why does not match the long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two distinct errors.

Firstly, the updating of `key1` must use `rValue` rather than `bValue`.

And secondly, the Delphi code performs arithmetic on `key1` in the context of `Word` which is a 2 byte unsigned integer. But the Java code performs the same calculations in the context of `int` which is a 4 byte signed integer.

To fix this I believe you simply need to perform the arithmetic using 4 byte signed and then truncate `key1` to a 2 byte value. Like this:

```
key1 = ((rValue[0]+key1)*key2+key3) & 0xffff;
```

I also think that you can simplify the Java code considerably. I know next to nothing about Java and so I'm sure a skilled Java expert could do very much better than this:

```
class SO15885898 {

    private static String ValueToHex(int myInt)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(myInt & 0xff));
        if (sb.length() < 2) {
            sb.insert(0, '0'); // pad with leading zero if needed
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int key1=11;        
        int key2=22;        
        int key3=33;

        String value = "ABCDE";
        for(int i=0; i<value.length(); i++){
            byte bValue = value.substring(i).getBytes()[0];
            int rValue = bValue^(key1>>8);
            key1 = ((rValue+key1)*key2+key3) & 0xffff;
            System.out.print(ValueToHex(rValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4144db69bf
```

---

On a more general note, since you have both codes, you should arrange that both codes are as close to each other in organisation as possible. And then print off as much diagnostics as possible to pinpoint the calculation step where differences first appear.

Comment: Wow thank you so so much. 
why i wasn't use 'rValue'!! 
It is my mistake. 
I have never tried a bit operations. 
so, it is so hard to me.