# delphi Decrypt convert Java Code

Tags: java, delphi, encryption

How can I convert the specific code written in Delphi to JAVA?

Delphi code is Decrypt code.

```
function Decrypt(const S: String; Key1, Key2, Key3: WORD): String;
var
  i: Byte;
  FirstResult: String;
begin
  FirstResult:=HexToValue(S);
  SetLength(Result, Length(FirstResult));
  for i:=1 to Length(FirstResult) do begin
    Result[i]:=Char(Byte(FirstResult[i]) xor (Key1 shr 8));
    Key1     :=(Byte(FirstResult[i])+Key1)*Key2+Key3;
  end;
end;

function HexToValue(const S: String) : String;
var i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(S) div 2);
  for i:=0 to (Length(S) div 2)-1 do begin
    Result[i+1] := Char(StrToInt('$'+Copy(S,(i*2)+1, 2)));
  end;
end;
```

The Encrypt problem was solved by courtesy of 'David Heffernan' and 'stackoverflow.com'

Question1 : [delphi encrypt convert Java Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885898/delphi-encrypt-convert-java-code)

thank so much!
so i tried to convert Decrypt code in Delphi to JAVA until now!!! really hum...
but i couldn't solve about it!! oh my god!
i'm shame.....
but i want you to help me. again... 
i need decrypt code ..

Java Encrypt code

```
class SO15885898 {

    private static String ValueToHex(int myInt)
    {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(myInt & 0xff));
    if (sb.length() < 2) {
        sb.insert(0, '0'); // pad with leading zero if needed
    }
    return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int key1=11;        
    int key2=22;        
    int key3=33;

    String value = "ABCDE";
    for(int i=0; i<value.length(); i++){
        byte bValue = value.substring(i).getBytes()[0];
        int rValue = bValue^(key1>>8);
        key1 = ((rValue+key1)*key2+key3) & 0xffff;
        System.out.print(ValueToHex(rValue));
    }
    }
}
```

please Java decrypt code!!
.
.

This is what I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 int key1=111;        
 int key2=222;        
 int key3=333;

 i tried about this...

 String resultH = "";
 String resultEncrypt = "";
 String resultDecrypt = "";
 String value = "ABCDEF";

 for(int i=0; i<value.length(); i++){
     byte bValue = value.substring(i).getBytes()[0];
     int rValue = bValue^(key1>>8);
     key1 = ((rValue+key1)*key2+key3) & 0xffff;
     resultEncrypt += ValueToHex(rValue);
  resultH += HexToValue(ValueToHex(rValue).getBytes()) ;
 }

 key1=111;
 for(int i=0; i<resultH.length(); i++){
     byte bValue = resultH.substring(i).getBytes()[0];
     int rValue = bValue^(key1>>8);
     key1 = ((rValue+key1)*key2+key3) & 0xffff;
     resultDecrypt += rValue;
 }

 //41db791e06a9
 System.out.println("resultEncrypt : " + resultEncrypt);
 //91242156862519211605712161341202650962331971751025.......................
 System.out.println("resultDecrypt : " + resultDecrypt);
}

public static byte[] HexToValue(byte[] szSrc) {
    int nLen = szSrc.length;
    byte[] szDest = new byte[nLen / 2];
    char szChar[] = new char[2];
    for (int I = 0; I < nLen / 2; I++) {
        szChar[0] = (char) szSrc[I * 2];
        szChar[1] = (char) szSrc[I * 2 + 1];
        byte btDest = (byte) HexToDecimal(szChar);
        int nDest = btDest < 0 ? (Byte.MAX_VALUE + 1) * 2 + btDest : btDest;
        szDest[I] = (byte) nDest;
    }
    String sRet = new String(szDest);
    return szDest;
}

public static int HexToDecimal(char[] szSrc) {
    int nRet = 0;
    int nLen = szSrc.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < nLen; i++) {
        byte cChar = (byte) szSrc[i];
        nRet = nRet * 16;
        nRet += HexToDecimal(cChar);
    }
    return nRet;
}
public static int HexToDecimal(byte cChar) {
    if (cChar == 'A' || cChar == 'a')
        return 10;
    if (cChar == 'B' || cChar == 'b')
        return 11;
    if (cChar == 'C' || cChar == 'c')
        return 12;
    if (cChar == 'D' || cChar == 'd')
        return 13;
    if (cChar == 'E' || cChar == 'e')
        return 14;
    if (cChar == 'F' || cChar == 'f')
        return 15;
    return (cChar - 48);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: i tried about this...
http://479lgs.blog.me/150165814698
But I did not succeed.

Comment: How didn't it succeed? What went wrong?

Comment: I was hoping that value of 'resultDecrypt' is 'ABCDEF'

Comment: This would be so much easier if you gave us complete programs. I cannot compile your Java as is. Where do I find `HexToValue`? I wish you would take more time and give us complete compilable programs. It's simple for you to do.

Comment: http://479lgs.blog.me/150165815357   <-- this is full source! Do you see it?

Comment: I don't want to see the full source in an offsite link. I want a minimal compilable program in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a translation of your Delphi code:

```
class SO15933038 
{

    private static int[] hexStringToIntArray(String s) 
    {
        int len = s.length();
        int[] data = new int[len / 2];
        for (int i=0; i<len; i+=2) {
            data[i / 2] =  ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                           + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

    private static String intArrayToHexString(int[] a)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length);
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            sb.append((char) a[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String Decrypt(String encrypted, int key1, int key2, int key3)
    {
        int[] input = hexStringToIntArray(encrypted);
        int[] output = new int[input.length];
        for (int i=0; i<output.length; i++)
        {
            output[i] = input[i]^(key1>>8) & 0xff;
            key1 = ((input[i]+key1)*key2+key3) & 0xffff;
        }
        return intArrayToHexString(output);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(Decrypt("41db791e06a9", 111, 222, 333));
    }
}
```

This is probably the lamest piece of Java ever written. Together with the answer to your previous question, I have now written two Java programs.

Comment: Thank you. I owe you for your answer
and I will study java language more.